# classes and access modifiers in .net

Tags: c#, oop, access-modifiers

I have 3 Questions regarding `Oops Concepts`:

1. What is the default access modifiers for class in the namespace, i tried to apply modifiers to the class, .net compiler threw error saying `Elements defined in namespace cannot be explicity declared as private, protected or protected friends. below is my code.
   [image: Access Modifiers for the class in c#]
2. What is the difference between `protected internal and internal` as internal could be used within the assembly, and protected internal could be used in the same class, inherited class or **the other classes within the same assembly**. and basically what exactly here meant by assembly.
3. If there is 2 class `Class1 and Class2` Class1 has `Method1()` and `Class2` has `Method2()`, if both are in the inherit chain, then `Class1 c = new Class2();` shall allow to access `Method2();` because here the new object is of `Class2` then why .net allows `Method1();` i tried this.

Comment: It's better to ask a single question here on S.O.

Comment: @Abbas, Nick is right - we are generally a one question, one answer community

Comment: Somehow I think that screenshot was photo-shopped. `class1` is not explicitly declared a private.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you know what I couldn't figure that one out either...  if you're right, that's *incredibly* strange behaviour indeed

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sometimes VS will give you errors from the previous time you attempted to build. The message doesn't make sense with the current state of the code, but I doubt he photoshoped it.

Comment: @Ingenu "Photoshopped" was figurative. It's just that we're not looking at the right code for the message. You're probably right about why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Internal

2) **Either** a derived class (potentially in a different assembly) **or** any code in the same assembly can access

3) You have a reference to a `class1` which doesn't have `method2` - you need a reference to a `class2` to be able to call `method2`.

Comment: if protected internal allows access to the code in the assembly then what is the difference between internal and protected internal, in that case i can use internal too, what's the use of Protected Internal

Comment: Because a class deriving from the class, but from another assembly, can still access the method/property/field as well

Answer (score 1):

As for question 2:

protected means that all derived classes can access the method, internal means that all classes inside this assembly can access the method. protected internal is the combination of both.

here is a very interesting blog post on protected internal methods:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/25/knights-knaves-protected-and-internal.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) There is there because you need to declare that class as protected or any higher access level e.g. public

3) Sub classes inherit Super classes members (in this case a method). The reverse cannot work although you are assigning class2 to a class1.